# Regex: Capture name and department separately

Tags: regex

Given text strings like

```
Assigned to: Hon Keith Davis Dept: S25
Assigned for All Purposes to: Hon. Howard Halm, Dept. 93
Judge Randolph M. Hammock Dept. 93
HONORABLE JOANNE B. O'DONNELL
Honorable Michael S. Williams
Judge:            Hon. Yolanda Orozco
```

I want to capture the name of the judge, and the department they are from, if available.

This is what I've come up with so far to capture just the name:

```
(?i)(?:(?:Hon(?:orable)?|Judge)(?:[:\. ]+))+((?-i)[A-Z][A-Za-z. '-]{3,})
```

The problem is that for the 1st and 3rd strings, the `Dept` portion is being captured, so I get `Keith Davis Dept` and `Randolph M. Hammock Dept`

When I tried to add a second capture group by appending

```
[, ]+(?:(?:Dept)[\.: ]+([A-Z0-9]+))?
```

to the above regex, it worked for the first 2 strings, but not the rest.

How can I exclude the `Dept` from the 1st capture group, and use a 2nd capture group to get out the department name / number?

Current regex and examples: https://regexr.com/4n85p

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that it's just 1 word, `Dept`.

Comment: Perhaps try it like this `(?i)(?:(?:Hon(?:orable)?|Judge)(?:[:\. ]+))+((?-i)[A-Z][A-Za-z. '-]{3}(?:(?![,]? Dept\b).)+)` See  https://regex101.com/r/iSaqeQ/1

Comment: `(?i)(?:(?:Hon(?:orable)?|Judge)[:. ]+)+((?-i)[A-Z][A-Za-z. '-]{3,})(?:[, ]+Dept[.: ]+([A-Z0-9]+))?$`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1COGZG/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice, that performs better than mine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! If you add your answer I'll gladly accept it

Comment: @Thefourthbird wiktor's regex take almost half steps  :), this is due to negative lookahead in your pattern right ?

Comment: @CodeManiac Tempered greedy token is always costly in terms of performance, but our regexps are just different, they yield different output, so I would not compare their performance.

Comment: @CodeManiac Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)(?:(?:Hon(?:orable)?|Judge)[:. ]+)+((?-i)[A-Z][A-Za-z. '-]{3,})(?:[, ]+Dept[.: ]+([A-Z0-9]+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1COGZG/2)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case sensitivity off
- `(?:(?:Hon(?:orable)?|Judge)[:. ]+)+` - 1+ occurrences of `Hon` or `Honorable` or `Judge` followed with 1+ colons, dots, spaces
- `((?-i)[A-Z][A-Za-z. '-]{3,})` - Group 1:

  - `(?-i)` - case sensitivity on
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
  - `[A-Za-z. '-]{3,}` - 3 or more ASCII letters, dots, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens
- `(?:[, ]+Dept[.: ]+([A-Z0-9]+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `[, ]+` - 1+ commas or spaces
  - `Dept` - a literal text
  - `[.: ]+` - 1+ dots, colons or spaces
  - `([A-Z0-9]+)` - Group 2: 1+ uppercase letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

More tips:

- If you want to only start matching at the whole words, add `\b` after `(?i)`
- To match any whitespace, replace literal spaces with `\s` (or `\h` - if supported - to match only horizontal whitespaces).

Answer (score 0):

```
.*(?:(?:H[Oo][nN](?:[oO][a-zA-Z]+(?:[^.])?)?)|(?:Judge:?))\.?\s*([a-zA-Z .']+),?\s*(?:Dept[:.]\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?\n
```

Please try the above expression in your [link](https://regexr.com/4n85p)

```
.*(?:(?:H[Oo][nN](?:[oO][a-zA-Z]+(?:[^.])?)?)|(?:Judge:?))\.?\s*(?<judge_name>[a-zA-Z .']+),?\s*(?:Dept[:.]\s*(?<department>[a-zA-Z0-9]+))?\n
```